# OSMC media center responding to volume buttons on TV in unknown fashion

Tags: hdmi, keyboard, kodi, osmc

I have an OSMC/Kodi media center set up with a raspberry pi 3, and I discovered to my surprise that pressing the volume buttons on the LG TV actually causes the raspberry pi to respond, but not with something related to volume. Sometimes I just hear clicking noises and nothing else, but other times some sort of menu comes up on the side with options that I don’t understand but seem to be a sort of “View preference” menu. During playback, the volume buttons on the tv both function as a “seek forward 10 seconds.”

I did not know control signals could be sent back through HDMI, and what’s more I definitely don’t know what signals the raspberry pi thinks I am sending. The system is operable as long as I don’t touch these volume controls, but I’d like to know what they’re doing.

Comment: do any other buttons on the remote do anything with the pi? If not, switch off CEC either on the TV or in OSMC (personally, I'd also try something like libreELEC instead of OSMC to see if it's a bug in OSMC's implementation of Kodi)

Comment: @Bravo IDK what CEC is. All functionality seems normal for the whole system, except that the on-unit TV volume buttons (possibly others too) operate the pi in mysterious ways.

Comment: yes, no need to repeat the problem. Are you using the TV remote for any other functionality for the pi? If so, then turning off CEC won't be a solution. If not: CEC is an option in Kodi somewhere, go through settings and find it ... and on LG TV's it can be known as SIMPLINK or something like that

Comment: Oh, do you have some sort of IR receiver on the pi and some other remote that you use for interacting with Kodi?

Comment: @Bravo I am using the OSMC official remote with USB dongle. The LG remote does not interface with the pi.

Comment: @Bravo No no, the buttons *on the tv unit* (as in the unit that shows the actual football game on its front) are affecting the pi, apparently via communication through the HDMI cable.

Comment: @Bravo Before it gets asked, I am sure this is actually the Pi showing the menu, and not the TV, because it makes the Kodi interface clock sound effects, and also has the right UI theme and size to be Kodi. Wish I’d investigated the menu more when I had a chance, but it’s an elderly friend of mine’s tv, so I’m not there right now. Will get more data soon.

Comment: Oh, so it's not the REMOTE! - yeah, turn off CEC in Kodi (not exactly sure where that is, sorry, it's in a configuration somewhere) and/or turn off "SIMPLINK" on the TV - again, it's a config somewhere on the TV this time

Comment: @Bravo That’s not particularly helpful. I mean, the original question was mostly to figure out what was happening, not how to stop it, since I can simply avoid it by not pushing the buttons on the TV.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the issue ... still, it's probably a CEC issue, disabling CEC will fix that

Comment: @Bravo I guess I’ll look up CEC then. Well, that’s something to go on. Thank you!

Comment: oh, what is happening ... I thought it was obvious. TV is sending CEC signals to the Pi that the Pi misinterprets